# Vbscript and imagemagick error resize

Tags: vbscript, imagemagick

I trying to rezise each subfolders first jpg and put it to new subfolder

```
Dim strFolderPath,objFSO
strDirectory= "D:\images\"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim objFolder, objSubFolder,folderCur 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

    Dim imageMagick
    Set imageMagick = CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1")


    If objFolder.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objSubFolder in objFolder.SubFolders



            'Now check if the folder contains any files.
            If objSubFolder.Files.Count > 0  Then
                folderCur = objSubFolder & "\_small320\"
                For each JpgFile in objSubFolder.Files
                WScript.Echo "Checking Folder: " & folderCur & "\" & JpgFile.name & vbcrlf & " File: "  & JpgFile

                    if not objFSO.folderexists(folderCur) then objFSO.createfolder folderCur
                    'imageMagick.Exec("convert " & JpgFile & " -resize 320x210 " & JpgFile.name)
                    imageMagick.Convert JpgFile, "-resize", "320x210", folderCur & "\preview.jpg"
                exit for
                next        
            End If 
        Next
    End If
```

But I get error on `imageMagick.Convert JpgFile, "-resize", "320x210", folderCur & "\preview.jpg"`

[image]

What is wrong with syntax?

also get this error

[image]

But all dlls exist in folder

Comment: You can take a look at this if you want ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714900/simple-hta-script-to-resize-folder-of-photos?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested (no ImageMagick at hand), but probably

```
imageMagick.Convert JpgFile.Path, "-resize", "320x210", folderCur & "preview.jpg"
```

Included full path to the file and removed an additional backslash in the output file (that was included in the folder name).

**EDITED** Now tested and working. This code processes subfolders of the folder where the script is placed.

```
Option Explicit

Const OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "_small320"

Dim fso
    Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim strScriptFolder    
    strScriptFolder = fso.GetFile( WScript.ScriptFullName ).ParentFolder.Path

Dim rootFolder
    Set rootFolder = fso.GetFolder( strScriptFolder )

Dim imageMagick
    Set imageMagick = WScript.CreateObject("ImageMagickObject.MagickImage.1")

Dim inputFolder, inputFile, strOutputFolder
    For Each inputFolder In rootFolder.SubFolders
        If inputFolder.Name <> OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME Then 
            strOutputFolder = fso.BuildPath(inputFolder.Path, OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME)
            If Not fso.FolderExists(strOutputFolder) Then 
                fso.CreateFolder strOutputFolder
            End If 
            For Each inputFile In inputFolder.Files
                Select Case LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(inputFile.Path))
                    Case "jpg", "jpeg", "png"
                        WScript.Echo "[ convert ] " & inputFile.Path
                        imageMagick.Convert inputFile.Path, _ 
                                            "-resize", _ 
                                            "320x210", _ 
                                            fso.BuildPath(strOutputFolder, inputFile.Name)
                    Case Else
                        WScript.Echo "[ skip    ] " & inputFile.Path
                End Select 
            Next 
        End If
    Next
```

The original error in question (`Unsupported argument type`) was generated when as argument a `File` object was passed, instead of a string with the file path.

The `Unable to load module` is an `ImageMagick` error, not a programming error. Maybe the `path` variable is wrong and the modules can not be found or it is a install error. The previous code has been tested (and works) with a fresh `ImageMagick-6.9.1-6-Q16-x64-dll.exe` install.